# Android - define groups in R.id

Tags: java, android, view

Is there any possibility to group the R.id?

```
android:id="@+id/button1"

R.id.button1
```

I want something like this:

```
android:id="@+id/main/button1"

R.id.main.button1
```

But that does not work.

Comment: I typically follow a naming scheme to keep things straight.  ie. main_button1, main_button2.

Comment: @WilliamMorrison this is a good solution for IntelliJ and Android Studio especially, I may be moving this direction in the near future myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I know to group like id's like that is to set all the tags the same. Then you get reference the id's with the same tag.

```
Button myButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
Button mySecondButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

myButton.setTag("Tag1");
mySecondButton.setTag("Tag1");
```

This way you can still programatically reference your group.

In the R.java file, the id itself *is* a group, and there is no way to superclass it with something else.

Answer (score 1):

As a matter of fact you can. This isn't documented, and IntelliJ does not play along nicely (Eclipse does), but you can do something like this...

***layout.xml***

```
android:id="@+id_group1/button1"
```

***Activity.java***

```
Button myButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id_group1.button1);
```